# Angular 2 RC5 and above - How to show an error page when no route matches?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, error-handling, routes

My current Route config looks like this

```
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'register/account',
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: 'register/account',
    component: AccountRegisterComponent
},
 {
    path: 'register/auto/:Id',
    component:AutoregisterComponent
},
```

If a user tries to navigate to '/register/auto'. Currently I see a blank page and an error in the console.
How can I show a 404 error or a message saying that this page is not available globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [angular2 cheatsheet](https://angular.io/cheatsheet)
You can do something like this:

```
{path: '**', redirectTo: '/404' }
```

So for example you would have something probably like this:

```
{path: '/404', component: NotFoundComponent},
{path: '**', redirectTo: '/404' }
```

Hope that helps